# Scenario with while statement

Tags: java, while-loop

Okay so I was working on understanding the bubble sort algorithm this code works but I dont understand the while statement? It doesnt have a condition in the parentheses and I dont know why it keeps on running and why it stops.

```
public class BubbleSort {
int temp;
boolean flag;
int[] bubbleSort(int[] bs)
{  
    flag=true;//What? 
    while(flag)//Whats happening here? Whats the condition
    {
    flag=false;//Wouldnt that quit the while loop?
    for(int i=0;i<bs.length-1;i++)
    {   
        if(bs[i]>bs[(i+1)])
        {
            temp=bs[i];
            bs[i]=bs[i+1];
            bs[i+1]=temp;
            flag=true;//What does this signify?
        }

    }
}
    return bs;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BubbleSort thisone = new BubbleSort();
    int[] bacon = {1,0,3,2,4,5};
    int[] potato = thisone.bubbleSort(bacon);
    for(int i=0;i<potato.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(potato[i]);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: "flag=false;//Wouldnt that quit the while loop?" Setting the flag won't quit the loop. *Evaluating* the flag, however, would quit the loop, and the while(flag) is where the flag is being evaluated. Order matters.

Comment: Although I'm sure you've come across it already, just in case, `while(flag)` is the same as `while(flag == true)`, just shorter. The answers can tell you what the flag means

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier to understand in pseudo-code, without all the language-specific stuff:

```
didSwap = true                          # force loop entry
while didSwap:                          # keep going until sorted
    didSwap = false                     # mark sorted
    for each element except last:
        if element > next element:
            swap element, next element
            didSwap = true              # swapped, mark possibly unsorted
```

The `didSwap` <sup>(a)</sup> variable is initially set to true to ensure the loop is entered.

Upon entering the loop, it is immediately set to false so that, it nothing sets it back to true, the loop will exit after this iteration. That means the default behaviour for a loop iteration is to complete, then exit the loop (all talk of iterations here and below refer to the *outer* loop, the `while` one, not the inner `for each` one).

Now look at what sets it back to true. It's the swapping of any items in this iteration. When that happens, you *know* that you need at least one more iteration of the loop because you may have disturbed the order of items you've already done earlier in this iteration.

Consider the case of the following numbers and you're part way through the first iteration (no swaps have yet been done):

```
5 10 15 7 20
     ^^
```

Running from left to right, you've arrived at the `15` and you know that the first three numbers are already in order. But then you get to the `7` and you swap it with `15` to fix the order of those two. Now you have:

```
5 10 7 15 20
       ^^
```

and you can see that, because you've made a change to the sequence *before* where you're processing, you may have disturbed the order (in fact you *have* in this case), so you'll need at least one more pass to check and/or fix that.

Bottom line, because of the sequential nature of processing the list (left to right), you can only be certain it's sorted if you reach the end of an iteration and no swaps have been performed during that iteration.

*That's* why the flag method is used. More naive implementations simply do something like `n * n` iterations for a list of size `n`. That also guarantees that the items will be sorted at the end but doesn't give you the early exit possibilities of the flag method. You can see the problem immediately if you give it an already-sorted list of a thousand elements.

The naive approach will process the entire list one thousand times, the flag method only once.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I prefer `didSwap` myself since its use and intent is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The `flag` is a typical Bubble sort optimization.  If you go through the entire array and make no changes, then the array is sorted, and you can stop.  `while(flag)` means "as long as the array still needs to be sorted."

In other words, the flag short circuits the sort.  It lets you stop early if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before entering the loop `flag` is set to `true` (otherwise it would not be able to enter)
2. As soon as it enters it sets `flag` to false
3. If a condition is met, the `flag` is set to `true`
4. Back to the top of the loop - is `flag` set ? If false, it will break out, otherwise back to step2

Answer (score 0):

`flag=true;//What?`

flag was declared earlier as a boolean, now it's being initialized to true (so that the loop will execute at least once)

`while(flag)//Whats happening here? Whats the condition`

A condition is just something that evaluates to a boolean, in this case the boolean variable `flag` *is* the condition.

`flag=false;//Wouldnt that quit the while loop?`

It won't jump out of the loop, that would take a `break` or `return`, so execution will continue into the for loop.

`flag=true;//What does this signify?`

This is set when `if(bs[i]>bs[(i+1)])` evaluates to true, signalling that the array is not sorted yet.